# Email Google Form Results not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a script to have form results e-mailed to me every time the form is submitted. Entire code is posted in Google Groups here:

http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/topic/apps-script/1rObNfuez6k/discussion

Here's the current code:

```
function contactUsMailer2(e) {

//    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
//    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data'); //default sheets - change if you
    var setup = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Setup'); //rename the sheets

    var width = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data').getLastColumn(); //get "width" of sheet, used to enumrate fields
    var myEmailAddress = setup.getRange('B3').getValue(); //get email recipient(s) from "Setup" (default)
    var myEmailSubject = setup.getRange('B4').getValue(); //get a subject line from "Setup" (default)
                                                          //from row 1 of "Data"
    var sheetURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl(); //get sheet url to include in email
    var formURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getFormUrl(); //get form url to include in email

    var column = 'A';
    var message = ''; 
    var htmlBody = '<html><body><table>'; //generated email will have both an HTML table and a plain-text part
                                          //to be RFC compliant.  beginning of html and table.
    for (var c=1; c<=width; ++c) {
        var data = sheet.getRange(1, c, 1, 1).getValue(); //this gets the "filed" names from the 1st row of "Sheet1"

        try {      
            //retrieve field data and build the HTML and plain-text emails
            var message = message + data + ': ' + e.namedValues[data].toString() + '\r\n'; //plain-text
            var htmlBody = htmlBody + '<tr><td><b>' + data + ': </b></td><td>' + e.namedValues[data].toString() + '</td></tr>'; //HTML
        }
        catch (a) {
            var message = message + data + ': n/a\r\n';
            var htmlBody = htmlBody + '<tr><td><b>' + data + ': </b></td><td>n/a</td></tr>';
        }

        var column = String.fromCharCode(column.charCodeAt() + 1); //increment column letter
    }

    var htmlBody = htmlBody + '</table>'; //close table

    var message = message + '\r\n\r\nData from form located at ' + formURL + '\r\n'; //put form url in text email
    var message = message + 'Data posted to spreadsheet at ' + sheetURL; //put sheet url in text email

    var htmlBody = htmlBody + '<br><br>Data from form located <a href=\"' + formURL + '\">here</a><br>'; //put form url in HTML email
    var htmlBody = htmlBody + 'Data posted to spreadsheet <a href=\"' + sheetURL + '\">here</a><br>'; //put sheet url in HTML email
    var htmlBody = htmlBody + '</body></html>'; //close html

    MailApp.sendEmail(myEmailAddress, myEmailSubject, message, {htmlBody: htmlBody}) ; //send the email
}

function showid() {
    Browser.msgBox("The sheet ID is:\r\n\r\n" + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
}
```

Script now works fine with the original spreadsheet, but when I try to use it with a new form and spreadsheet it fails to send the e-mail. The form fill in the spreadsheet just fine and we get the usual e-mail stating that the spreadsheet has been updated, but the script e-mail doesn't come through.

Funny thing is when I debug the script it does send the e-mail, just null entries in all fields (which is what I would expect). Debug doesn't report any errors in the script itself. What am I missing?

Comment: It fails, but what's the error message? If you can't see it because it's in a trigger, set the trigger notification options to send it to you immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure trigger is set to "On Submit". Mine was set to "On Open".

Answer (score 1):

Have you authorized the script in your new form ? Since your script is required to send out an email it requires explicit authorization.

Comment: Yes I authorized it but your question sent me to recheck triggers. Trigger was set to "On Open" rather then "On Submit". Was sure I had it set right. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quote around
`for (var c=1; c<=width; ++c) {
      var data = sheet.getRange(column + '1').getValue(); //this gets the "filed" names from the 1st row of "Sheet1"`

I do something similar in a script and the following works for me.

`var rangeval = "B"+(i+1);
var nameFld = filesheet.getRange(i+1,1).getValue();`

Joe

Comment: Sorry Joe, I should have posted code here. The like you reference has been corrected as it was the problem that brought about the original post. Here's the current code: